# Is there any python code to convert multipage pdf to images without using ImageMagick or Ghost Script

Tags: python, image, pdf

Is there any python code to convert multipage  pdf to images without using ImageMagick or Ghost Script.

wand.image is having import error

Comment: Perhaps, pdfimages. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages. It is not python, but you can likely call it from python using a subprocess call.

Comment: Thanks buddy but I want the complete pdf as image.

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want to convert the multi-page pdf to separate raster images, such as png or jpg? Or as a multipage tiff? Or as separate pdf files? Please give more details. Your post is not very clear what you want as the output. If Wand cannot read your PDF, then it is likely that Ghostscript is missing from the ImageMagick install that is needed with Wand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with [PyMuPDF](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I don't think ImageMagick or GhostScript are used behind the scenes.

```python
import os

import fitz


pdf_filename = r'C:\SomeDocument.pdf'
pdf_dirname = os.path.dirname(pdf_filename)
pdf_basename = os.path.basename(pdf_filename)
pdf_root, pdf_ext = os.path.splitext(pdf_basename)
img_filename_fmt = '{}_{}_of_{}.png'

pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_filename)
for page_index in range(pdf_document.pageCount):
    img_filename = os.path.join(pdf_dirname, img_filename_fmt.format(pdf_root, page_index + 1, pdf_document.pageCount))
    page_pixmap = pdf_document.getPagePixmap(page_index)
    page_pixmap.writePNG(img_filename)
pdf_document.close()
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. fitz requires Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 to be installed. But it is unavailable now

Comment: Did you try `pip install PyMuPDF` instead of `pip install fitz`?